# Is there a python function to expand dates (similar to List.Dates in power query)?

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas I want to be able to expand my 'end date' column, by the 'number of days' column as illustrated below:

```
| Employee Code | End Date  | Number Of Days |
|          2501 | 1/9/2020  |              4 |
|          2501 | 1/2/2020  |              1 |
|          2502 | 1/20/2020 |              3 |
|          2503 | 1/15/2020 |              2 |
```

Expected Output :

```
    | Employee Code  | End Date   | Number Of Days  |Expanded date   |
    |  2501          |  1/9/2020  |  4              |  1/9/2020      | 
    |  2501          |  1/9/2020  |  4              |  1/8/2020      | 
    |  2501          |  1/9/2020  |  4              |  1/7/2020      | 
    |  2501          |  1/9/2020  |  4              |  1/6/2020      | 
    |  2501          |  1/2/2020  |  1              |  1/2/2020      | 
    |  2502          |  1/20/2020 |  3              |  1/20/2020     | 
    |  2502          |  1/20/2020 |  3              |  1/19/2020     | 
    |  2502          |  1/20/2020 |  3              |  1/18/2020     | 
    |  2503          |  1/15/2020 |  2              |  1/15/2020     | 
    |  2503          |  1/15/2020 |  2              |  1/14/2020     |
```

Is there a simple way to do this in pandas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 3):

Do `reindex` with `repeat` then `cumcount` get the expected date

```
df=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['Number Of Days']))
df['Exp Date']=df['End Date']-pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),unit='D')
df
   Employee Code   End Date  Number Of Days   Exp Date
0           2501 2020-01-09               4 2020-01-09
0           2501 2020-01-09               4 2020-01-08
0           2501 2020-01-09               4 2020-01-07
0           2501 2020-01-09               4 2020-01-06
1           2501 2020-01-02               1 2020-01-02
2           2502 2020-01-20               3 2020-01-20
2           2502 2020-01-20               3 2020-01-19
2           2502 2020-01-20               3 2020-01-18
3           2503 2020-01-15               2 2020-01-15
3           2503 2020-01-15               2 2020-01-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Much longer route than @Yoben's, using pandas' [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with some `itertools` love :

```
phase1 = ((code, 
           date, 
           num,
           pd.date_range(end=date,periods=num)[::-1])
          for code, date, num in df.to_numpy()
         )

from itertools import product,chain
flatten = chain.from_iterable
phase2 = flatten(product([rest],expanded_date) for *rest, expanded_date in phase1)
phase3 = [(*rest, expanded) for rest, expanded in phase2]


cols = df.columns.tolist()

cols.append("Expanded Date")
pd.DataFrame(phase3, columns = cols)

Employee Code   End Date    Number Of Days  Expanded Date
0   2501       2020-01-09   4                2020-01-09
1   2501       2020-01-09   4                2020-01-08
2   2501       2020-01-09   4                2020-01-07
3   2501       2020-01-09   4                2020-01-06
4   2501       2020-01-02   1                2020-01-02
5   2502       2020-01-20   3                2020-01-20
6   2502       2020-01-20   3                2020-01-19
7   2502       2020-01-20   3                2020-01-18
8   2503       2020-01-15   2                2020-01-15
9   2503       2020-01-15   2                2020-01-14
```